# Is it possible to POST a user's answer to a QuestionObject using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

Currently we can use the Graph API to

- GET all the Questions a user has asked
- GET Question to see its QuestionOptions
- GET QuestionOption's /votes to see what users voted for each option
- POST a new Question to a user's wall
- POST new QuestionOptions to a Question

This is all great. But I want to answer a question on behalf of a user. Is it possible to POST a user's vote to a Question?

Answer (score 1):

Having the answers ID, you just do a http post like at https://graph.facebook.com/option_id

I tested at [Facebook Explorer Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and it worked for me.

I probably explained myself in a wrong way, when i said option_id, i ment the option id u get from the question options, like:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(*FacebookToken);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.fields = "id,question,from,is_published,options.fields(votes,name,**id**,vote_count)";

//Loads the question

dynamic question = client.Get(**questionID, parameters);

foreach (dynamic opt in question.options.data)
{ 
    //set the first answer as the choosed one for example
    client.Post(opt.id, null);
    break;
}

* the token u got
** the question id you want to load and answer
```